# typedef enum: Different values for one member

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I'm wondering if I can assign different values to the same member of an typedef enum like this...:

```
typedef enum {

    START   = 0x01,
    DATA    = 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
    CRC     = 0x0A, 0x0B

}bytes_t;
```

...so I can later use it like this:

```
bytesReceived++;                        // incremented for every received byte

switch (bytesReceived) {

    case START:
        dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];              
        break;

    case DATA:
        dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

    case CRC:
        dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

}
```

So the program carries out the `DATA` case eight times if called in a loop. Does this work? It's only a first idea, so I can't give you further context unfortunately.

Comment: You can't really assign multiple values to one name. What you can do, however, is to add multiple cases sharing the code in the `switch` statement.

Comment: `enum` type is not that complicated type of structure, so you can't literally do a lot with it, like the one you asked. But there are other data structures and `if`s and `switch`s that can help you through.

Comment: No, but you may want to learn about bit masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jacajack, You can't assign multiple values to one enum member variable, However you can achieve the same thing by using a switch logic. with multiple values for `byteReceived` result in same logic get executed. I hope follwing snippet will be useful.

```
switch (bytesReceived) {

    case START:
        dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];              
        break;

    case 0x02: //List all the cases, for which same action needs to be executed.
    case 0x03:
    case 0x04:
    case 0x05:
    case 0x06:
        dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

    case CRC:
        dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. Enum is a constant with a distinct value.
Use multiple cases:

```
typedef enum {
    START   = 0x01,
    DATA_2  = 0x02, 
    DATA_3  = 0x03,
    DATA_4  = 0x04,
    ...
    DATA_9  = 0x09,
    CRC_1   = 0x0A, 
    CRC_2   = 0x0B
}bytes_t;

switch (variable) {
    case START:
        dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];              
        break;
    case DATA_2:
    case DATA_3:
    ...
    case DATA_9:
        dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;
    case CRC_1:
    case CRC_2:
        dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;
}
```

or use `if` with a range:

```
typedef enum {
    START   = 0x01,
    DATA_START  = 0x02, 
    DATA_STOP   = 0x09,
    CRC_1     = 0x0A, 
    CRC_2     = 0x0B
}bytes_t;

if (variable == START) {
        dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
} else if (DATA_START <= variable && variable <= DATA_STOP) {
        dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
} else if (variable == CRC_1 || variable == CRC_2) {
        dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is probably not what you want here. I would so something like this:

```
#define START   0x01
#define DATA    0x02
#define CRC     0x0A
#define INVALID 0x0C

if (bytesReceived >= INVALID){
    // throw error
} else if (bytesReceived >= CRC){
    dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
} else if (bytesReceived >= DATA){
    dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
} else if (bytesReceived >= START){
    dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
}
```

This way you can edit the ranges without having to change a large amount of switch statements every time. There are even more systematic ways to do this, but for a simple application such as what you presented, this would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Each `enum` name can have only one value. Here are some alternatives you can use.

As imans77 pointed out in comments, you can use `if` statements instead of `switch`

```
if ( bytesReceived == 0x01 ) handle_start( );
else if ( bytesReceived < 0x0a ) handle_data( );
else handle_crc( );
```

Or if you really want to keep the `enum` and the `switch`, you can do it as everyone else here pointed out:

```
enum
{
   START = 0x01,
   DATA0 = 0x02,
   DATA1 = 0x03,
   ...
   DATA7 = 0x09,
   CRC1 = 0x0a,
   CRC2 = 0x0b
} byte_t;

switch ( bytesReceived )
{
   case START: handle start( ); break;

   case DATA0:
   case DATA1:
   case DATA2:
   ...
   case DATA7:
        handle_data( );
        break;

   case CRC1:
   case CRC2:
        handle_crc( );
        break;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Each name in an `enum` must have a single value.  A symbol can't represent multiple values at once.

```
typedef enum {
    START   = 0x01,
    DATA2   = 0x02,
    DATA3   = 0x03,
    DATA4   = 0x04,
    DATA5   = 0x05,
    DATA6   = 0x06,
    DATA7   = 0x07,
    DATA8   = 0x08,
    DATA9   = 0x09,
    CRCA    = 0x0A,
    CRCB    = 0x0B,
}bytes_t;
```

What you can do in your `switch` statement is take advantage of case fallthrough to have multiple cases do the same thing:

```
switch (bytesReceived) {

    case START:
        dPkg->startByte = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];              
        break;

    case DATA2:
    case DATA3:
    case DATA4:
    case DATA5:
    case DATA6:
    case DATA7:
    case DATA8:
    case DATA9:
        dPkg->data = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

    case CRCA:
    case CRCB:
        dPkg->crc = dpkgRxBuffer[bytesReceived];
        break;

}
```